# Is it worth it to leave PHP and study Python just for Google App Engine?

Tags: php, python, google-app-engine

I'm a PHP developer and don't have any experience with Python.
Since GAE seems promising, I really want to use it as my back-end for web apps and mobile games.
I found 'Quercus' but I just want more native way.

Does it worth to leave PHP and study Python just for Google App Engine?
Or will PHP be available for GAE in the near future?

Comment: It is worth it anyway to learn multiple languages. For the sake of diversity and different viewing angles of a problem.

Comment: I agree with Dykam. But it depends whether you have time to learn or you are short of time and needs only to make things work.

Comment: Anything that meas you learn to code in something other than PhP is worth doing.

Comment: Language Agnosticism my friend! :D

Comment: Anyone can point out alternative to GAE for PHP? I've found phpfog & cloudcontrol. Are there other services I jump over?

Comment: Devyn: that depends how well you feel with systems administration. If you fine with that, AWS is viable alternative.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just for GAE? No. For many other reasons -- absolutely.

[Related question on programmers.stackexchange](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/65967/is-python-a-scripting-web-language-that-can-be-used-for-web-development)